# Checking if Char contains numbers and converting it to INT

Tags: c

Well there is program doing it's function right, but I am trying to make it check, if user-entered value is number(doesn't contain letters or signs). So basically I am using if with isdigit or '/0' condition. Program compiles properly, but I am getting error, when entering less than 3 types(even numbers...). What is wrong with it? Only thing I need is to skip loop when number is 0-999 and re-ask while it isn't, or if it is not number.

```
char x[5];
bool isgood;
int tab[20][2],i=0,a;
do
{
    isgood = TRUE;
    printf("Write a where 0<a<1000\n");
    scanf("%4s", x);
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (isdigit(x[j])==0 || x[j]!='/0') isgood = FALSE;
    }
    a = atoi(x);
    if (a<1000 && isgood == TRUE)   break;
} while (1);
```

Comment: Actually, the terminating zero is either plain `0` or `'\0'`. Your compiler should have warned you.

Comment: @WhozCraig actually if isgood goes FALSE it's not really important, since loop repeats only for 4 times.

Comment: @Dnoren ah. mental floss 101. Its definitely friday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrong:**

- Your boolean-logic
- Your null-character
- Calling `atoi` when `isgood` is `FALSE`

---

**Change this:**

```
isdigit(x[j])==0 || x[j]!='/0'
```

**To this:**

```
isdigit(x[j])==0 && x[j]!='\0'
```

**And this:**

```
a = atoi(x);
if (a<1000 && isgood == TRUE)   break;
```

**To this:**

```
if (isgood == TRUE)
{
    a = atoi(x);
    if (0<a && a<1000)
        break;
}
```

**Here is a far more simple way of doing the whole thing:**

```
int x;
char c;
do
{
    printf("Write a where 0<a<1000\n");
    if (scanf("%d",&x) == 0)
        scanf("%c",&c);
    else if (0<x && x<1000)
        break;
}
while (1);
```

Comment: Simple way is not really working. When i type something different than digit, then program goes crazy. Either correcting what you said did not help, but I see they shall be way you said anyway.

Comment: @Dnoren: Yep, I see what you mean. Please see revised code at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Well it almost works now but still some issues.

1)When i type invalid value(like 'aaaa') it shows message "Write a where 0<a<1000\n" for 4 times(same number as invalid chars i wrote).
2)This one is worse. When i type mixed value like '5bb5' it accepts this, even tough 'bb' are not digits.

Comment: @Dnoren: In order to avoid the repeating message, you can put it outside the loop (above the `do`), and inside the loop, as an additional `else` condition (after the `else if`). I'm afraid that the purpose of this website is for users to give you general insights to your problems, not to write-down the entire program to your complete satisfaction.

Comment: I understand purpose of this site, but with Your solutions I don't really get what happends in this. Exactly this line:
if (scanf("%d", &a) == 0)
I though it checks, if 'a' got proper value as %d(int) variable, but since it accepts any value containing at least one digit, I don't really understand what does it do.

Comment: @Dnoren: It scans for an integer. If the user input doesn't start with something that represents an integer, then it fails and returns 0. After that, several additional calls to `scanf` are required, in order to scan all the non-digit characters that were inputted by the user.